# Multiple reactive Spring statemachine 3.2.0 instances run a single thread in OpenShift 4

Tags: spring, openshift, threadpool, reactive, state-machine

I'm running a Springboot (2.5.9) service that creates Spring statemachine 3.2.0 instances.
Java SDK version is 11.0.17
I have a weird behavior when springboot service runs within OpenShift 4 Pod; all statemachine instances run the same parallel thread whereas each statemachine runs its own poolable thread on a laptop running Windows OS.
Thanks a lot for any hint!
Some searches results suggested to configure a thread pool to run statemachine instances such as following example (https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/#statemachine-config-commonsettings), but such option doesn't look like to be available for reactive async state machines.

## Pod's running OS

`$ uname -a  Linux gin-backend-numerisation-dev-5897964856-vplzb 4.18.0-305.57.1.el8_4.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 5 17:55:55 EDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

## Pod's Java version:

`$ java --version  openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode, sharing)`

## Local machine's output (normal behavior)

`2023-04-12 08:10:24.978 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Starting State Machine [Instance_2]...

2023-04-12 08:10:25.050 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.061 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.062 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [null] to [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.064 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- state machine started: [Instance_2]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.065 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Started [Instance_2]...

2023-04-12 08:10:25.066 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Starting State Machine [Instance_1]...

2023-04-12 08:10:25.066 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.067 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.068 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [null] to [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.068 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- state machine started: [Instance_1]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.069 [GIN] [restartedMain] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Started [Instance_1]...

2023-04-12 08:10:25.070 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [INITIAL] to [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.072 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_2] Received message: [null] From: [INITIAL] To: [STARTED] Running action: [StartAction]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.078 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - --------------------- Waiting for future state event...

2023-04-12 08:10:25.376 [GIN] [parallel-2] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.376 [GIN] [parallel-2] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.377 [GIN] [parallel-2] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [INITIAL] to [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.377 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_1] Received message: [null] From: [INITIAL] To: [STARTED] Running action: [StartAction]

2023-04-12 08:10:25.377 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - --------------------- Waiting for future state event...

2023-04-12 08:10:26.557 [GIN] [GIN-Async2] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ----------------------- Completing future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.557 [GIN] [GIN-Async1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ----------------------- Completing future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.557 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ------------------- Consumed completed future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.557 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ------------------- Consumed completed future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.561 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - -------------------- sending event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.561 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - -------------------- sending event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.571 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.571 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.572 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.572 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.573 [GIN] [parallel-4] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [STARTED] to [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.573 [GIN] [parallel-3] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [STARTED] to [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.573 [GIN] [parallel-5] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_2] Received message: [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT] From: [STARTED] To: [REJECT_DOCUMENT] Running action: [RejectDocumentAction]

2023-04-12 08:10:26.573 [GIN] [parallel-6] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_1] Received message: [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT] From: [STARTED] To: [REJECT_DOCUMENT] Running action: [RejectDocumentAction]`

## Openshift's output - Unexpected behavior: 2 instances running a single thread (parallel-1)

`2023-04-12 08:37:48.128 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Started SpringBootApplication in 70.821 seconds (JVM running for 74.85)

2023-04-12 08:37:48.212 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Starting State Machine [Instance_1]...

2023-04-12 08:37:48.693 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.702 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.705 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [null] to [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.707 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- state machine started: [Instance_1]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.707 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Started [Instance_1]...

2023-04-12 08:37:48.708 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Starting State Machine [Instance_2]...

2023-04-12 08:37:48.709 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.798 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [null] to [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.798 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- state machine started: [Instance_2]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.799 [GIN] [main] INFO  c.q.h.g.SpringBootApplication - Started [Instance_2]...

2023-04-12 08:37:48.802 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.813 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [INITIAL] to [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.815 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [INITIAL]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.816 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.817 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [INITIAL] to [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.821 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_1]`

Received message: [null] From: [INITIAL] To: [STARTED] Running action: [StartAction]

2023-04-12 08:37:48.900 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - --------------------- Waiting for future state event...

2023-04-12 08:37:53.699 [GIN] [GIN-Async1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ----------------------- Completing future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.699 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ------------------- Consumed completed future state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.704 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - -------------------- sending event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.797 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State exited [STARTED]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.807 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State entered [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.808 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.StateMachineEventListener - ----- State changed from [STARTED] to [REJECT_DOCUMENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.813 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - ----- consuming state event [REJECT_DOCUMENT_EVENT]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.813 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - State Machine: [Instance_2] Received message: [null] From: [INITIAL] To: [STARTED] Running action: [StartAction]

2023-04-12 08:37:53.828 [GIN] [parallel-1] INFO  c.q.h.g.s.a.StateMachineAction - --------------------- Waiting for future state event\